# How to run a command in C# Console Application using switches in the command?

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to run a command in my C# console app but keeps failing with

```
'w:\start' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The drive gets mapped successfully and can run the command with just using `@"/C W:\Setup.exe"` but as you can see in the below code there are switches now:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c w:\start /wait setup.exe /auto upgrade /NoReboot /DynamicUpdate disable /showoobe None /Telemetry Disable").WaitForExit();
```

And when I run the app it gives me the above error?  Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you go from `@"/C W:\Setup.exe"` to `@"/c w:\start /wait setup.exe ..."`, and what part of the error message don't you understand? Do you mean `@"/c start W:\Setup.exe ..."`? Why do you think you need `start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `setup.exe` is on `W:` drive, you can write:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c start /wait ""Some Title"" w:\setup.exe /auto upgrade /NoReboot /DynamicUpdate disable /showoobe None /Telemetry Disable").WaitForExit();
```

Indeed, using the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command line command with options you need to specify a title for the console window, between `start` options and the file to execute and its own options.

Comment: Thanks,  it is working perfectly now! :-)

Comment: Thank you as well for the explanation! :-)